# Source Code behind call graph tool in visual studio

Tags: c#, dependencies, call-graph

how to get list of objects referenced specific class or method.
like

```
class Calculator
{
     public decimal Add(decimal x, decimal y)
     {
         return x+y;
     }

}

class Main
{

     private sum(decimal A, decimal b)
     {
        calculater c = new calculater();
        c.Add(A,B);
     }
}
```

i want list of objects that call Calculator class and call add function specifically.

Thank You.